# How to ignore files ended with ~ in git?

Tags: git, gitignore

My `.gitignore` file looks like that:

```
> cat .gitignore
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3
log/*.log
tmp/**/*
*~
```

But, git doesn't ignore the files ended with `~`:

```
> git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb
#   modified:   app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb~
#   modified:   public/stylesheets/jobs_new_edit.css~
```

What could be th ereason for that?

Comment: I think @kan's answer it exactly what you want, and I have a personal suggestion: add `set nobackup` to your `.vimrc`. Then it'll not generate the `*.*~` files anymore. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`modified` means you have the file committed in the repo already. You should remove it first, then it will be ignored for addition.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have it versioned, it was added to the repository (or index) before.