# gitignore match files with pre and suffix in subdirectory

Tags: git, gitignore

I like to track only files that start with "es" and end with *.h or *.m

so i tried this:

```
#exlude all
*
#except
!es*.h
!es*.m
```

and

```
#exlude all
*
#except
!*/es*.h
!*/es*.m
```

but neither works for files in subdirectories

Comment: Just tried, it works for me. Maybe you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Maybe case sensitivity? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678325 ? Or CR-LF vs CR?

Comment: i noticed it just doesn't work for subdirectories

Comment: Try and add `!*/es*.m` and `!*/es*.h` to your .gitignore

Comment: @peko, I say _add_, which means you should also leave the origin `!es*.h` and `!es*.m` in

Comment: @fge, tried that too, doesnt work either for files in subdirectories

Comment: Well then, just ignore everything and `git add -f` them as they appear, I see no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ignore everything (`*`), you ignore folders, even if they have contents too, as `*` matches everything.

If you *unignore* something, that would be matched only for the *files* of the root dir. If you need to unignore a directory, you need to explicitly say that (ie `!mydir/`). But that would unignore all the contents of that dir, so you'd have to redefine the ignore/unignore pattern for the contents of that dir. Even if you do that, if you haven't already added the dir to the index, you won't see that in `git status`.

Your case can be solved easily but inverting the pattern.
What you basically want to do is ignore everything that

- does not start with `es` *and*
- does not end with `.h` *or* `.m`.

So do that:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  .git  .gitignore  a  b  blah  c  ebar.m  esfoo.h  esfoo.m  sbar.m
$ ls -a blah/
.  ..  a  b  c  ebar.m  esfoo.h  esfoo.m  sbar.m
$ git status -s
?? blah/
?? esfoo.h
?? esfoo.m
$ git status -s blah/   # matching files ignored and also ignored on `git add`
?? blah/esfoo.h
?? blah/esfoo.m
$ git add .
$ git status -s         # only wanted files were added
A  blah/esfoo.h
A  blah/esfoo.m
A  esfoo.h
A  esfoo.m
$ cat .gitignore        # the ignore pattern -- ignore
[^e]*                   # everything that doesn't start with 'e'
e[^s]*                  # and is not followed by an 's'
*.[^hm]                 # and does not end with '.h' or '.m'
!/blah                  # uningore the wanted subdirs
```

As you see in the last command, I've inverted your pattern to ignore everything that doesn't start with `e` and is not followed by an `s` and that doesn't end with `.h` or `.m` and also unignored a dir. Even though the dir had more content, it was ignored as it matched the pattern, and only the wanted parts were added.

*edit*: updated

Comment: close one, but i getting files starting with 'e' or 's' too (like bla/efoo.bar or bla/sfoo.bar)

Comment: fixed, I believe, check it ;) new ignore pattern (see revised last paragraph) and example