# gitignore all files except all java files in subdirectory

Tags: regex, git, github, gitignore

I've tried a bunch of different methods.

1.

```
*
!.gitignore
!./src/com/AleXander/*
```

2.

```
/*
!.gitignore
!src/com/Alexander/*.java
```

3.

```
*
!.gitignore
!./*.java
```

as well as multiple other variations of this.  I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850203/gitignore-match-files-with-pre-and-suffix-in-subdirectory) that looks like it's using Regex.  Is regex needed for this to work?  Any ideas?

I also tried these regex patterns but I am not the best at regex.

1.**Logic:** ignore all files ending with the file extension pattern "java"

```
*
!.gitignore
!*.[^java$]
```

2.**Logic:** ignore all files ending with a "j" followed by an "a" with anything else after that.

```
 *
 !.gitignore
 !*.j[^a]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring `*` is a bad idea.
This will ignore every file and every directory in every part of your repository.

Especially git will not look at all at ignored directories. Therefore the exceptions you define later will have no effect at all.

There are quite longish include/exclude hacks to make something like this work, but usually the best way is to just explicitly ignore the files you want to ignore and avoid any exceptions whenever possible.

If you feel the need for some more complicated ignore rules this is usually an indicator that your repository layout needs a better structure.